# Adding tabindex in Vue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a couple of inputs that get created dynamically when the user clicks on a button. The problem is that when you navigate them with Tab the tab indexes are not correct. How can I set the tabindex for them properly so that one can navigate through them in order?

Here is the component html:

```
<div class="captable-creation-container" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control input"  placeholder="Username" name="username">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input"  placeholder="Share Amount" name="shareAmount">
    
    </div>
     <div class="shareholder-p-container">
        <div class="new-inputs-container">
          
          <div id="platform-name-container"> </div>
          <div id="initial-options-pool-container"></div>
        </div>
        <p class="add-new-shareholders-p" @click="createNewDistributionShareholder"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"/>ADD NEW SHAREHOLDER</p>
</div>
```

and the creation of the inputs:

```
createNewDistributionShareholder() { var newPlatformNameInputContainer = document.getElementById('platform-name-container')

    const newPlatformNameInput = document.createElement('input')
    newPlatformNameInput.classList.add('form-control')
    newPlatformNameInput.classList.add('input')
    newPlatformNameInput.placeholder = 'Username'
    newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute("name", 'username');

   newPlatformNameInputContainer.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput)
 
 var secondContainer = document.getElementById('initial-options-pool-container')

    const newInitialOptionsPool = document.createElement('input')
    newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add('form-control')
    newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add('input')
    newInitialOptionsPool.placeholder = 'Shares Amount'
    newInitialOptionsPool.name = 'poolOptions'
    newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute('type', 'text')
    newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute("name", 'shareAmount');
    secondContainer.appendChild(newInitialOptionsPool);
},
import $ from 'jquery'

$(document).ready(function() {
    var 
    input = $(".input"),
    //set tab index to starts from 1
    tabindex = 0;   
    input.each(function() {
    // add tab index number to each list items
    tabindex++; 
    $(this).attr("tabindex","TabIndex  " +tabindex); 

    var tabIndex = $(this).attr("tabindex");
    // add tab index number to each list items as their title   
    $(this).attr("tabindex",tabIndex);
    })
});
```

I tried using Jquery but it still does not work!

Comment: Why do you think the tabindexes are wrong?

Comment: @AlbertAllagulov What else could be causing the out of order focusing using Tab besides the tabindexes?